# Javascript regex for RPM naming convention

Tags: javascript, regex, naming-conventions, rpm

While RPM will run just as well if a package file has been renamed, when the packages are created during RPM's build process, they follow a specific naming convention. The convention is:

```
name-version-release.architecture.rpm
```

- **Name**
  An RPM package name is short and descriptive. If multiple words are used, they
  are separated by hyphens (not underscores, as you might expect). Typical
  names include binutils, caching-nameserver, cvs, gmc, kernel-source, and telnet.
- **Version**
  Each package has a version. Most package versions are the same as that of the
  software they contain. The format of package versions varies from package to
  package, but most are numeric ( major.minor.patchlevel ).
- **Revision**
  The revision tag is simply a release number for the package. It has no significance
  except to determine whether one package is newer than another when the ver-
  sion number does not change.
- **Architecture** : can be : i386,x86_64,alpha,sparc,mips,ppc,m68k or SGI.

We try this regex  :

```
 /[a-z][A-z][-](\-)[0-9](\.)[0-9](\.)[0-9](\-)[i386|x86_64|alpha|sparc|mips|ppc|m68k|SGI]/i;
```

I get an error.

## Example of validate names (without rpm extension):

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How are you using the regex?

Comment: Can you provide actual examples of input? Do you want to match all the string (so validate that the format is correct) or parse it?

Comment: see update. And thx for who is intersted

Comment: `[i386|alpha|sparc|mips|ppc|m68k|SGI]` should be `(i386|alpha|sparc|mips|ppc|m68k|SGI)`.. check the bracket types.

Comment: What do you want to do with this regex? Catch the name, version, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is not to use a regex but to actually [parse](http://yum.baseurl.org/gitweb?p=yum.git;a=blob;f=rpmUtils/miscutils.py;h=aea455082c91c51bcc5986174c2bd1f699ff1d94;hb=HEAD#l301) the name the way the python rpm utilities do it. Once you've done that you can validate or verify any of the individual fields you want.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
/^[a-z-]+-[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*-[a-z0-9.]+\.(?:i386|x86_64|alpha|sparc|mips|ppc|m68k|SGI)$/i;
```